# Component 404 is not working properly. Why is page not found not working?

Tags: angular, routes

I don't know how to deal with it. The code looks like a pattern.
Page is not loading. Here are my paths.

[Does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfGTE.jpg)

[it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk71B.jpg)

Can anyone explain why this is so?
Thanks for your comments

I did routing according to the pattern.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/page-not- 
found/page-not-found.component';
import { DetailComponent } from 
'./pages/detail/detail.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from 
'./pages/register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [

 { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
 { path: ':id', component: DetailComponent },

 { path: '**', pathMatch:'full', component: 
  PageNotFoundComponent },

];
@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
 })
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In my path '**' setting doesn't work for me ...

if I change the order of a track, it works

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },

 { path: '**', pathMatch:'full', component: 
  PageNotFoundComponent },

 { path: ':id', component: DetailComponent },
 ];
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you. Images don't count, paste your code as code blocks!

Comment: I did a code update